# Enable www + HTTPS on Entire Site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

The problem is this, if I enter https://example.com and don't include the www, it will not add www. If I enter http://example.com, it will add the www and HTTPS by itself. Please look at this code, any help is greatly appreciated. This is what's in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(acceptoffer|login|register|admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Did not work for me, the www infront of the domain has gone away and some pages broke. Please check mac metro dot com and let me know.

Comment: I have added the original code back until we find a solution.

Comment: No problem dude, have fun. :P